# Etrade API Oauth 1.0 flow fails with invalid oauth_signature

Tags: python, java, go, oauth, etrade-api

I would like to authenticate against the Etrade API using Go and Postman. I am following the official [Etrade API Developer Docs](https://developer.etrade.com/home):

[image: Etrade API welcome page]

I successfully completed the Oauth 1.0 flow using the Python example they provided (with some [slight modifications](https://github.com/natemurthy/etrade-api/blob/main/python/etrade_python_client/etrade_python_client.py#L74-L82) to print some of the session attributes):

```
$ python3 etrade_python_client.py

1)  Sandbox Consumer Key
2)  Live Consumer Key
3)  Exit
Please select Consumer Key Type: 2

Please accept agreement and enter verification code from browser: REDACTED
access_token_response: <Response [200]>
access_token: REDACTED
access_token_secret: REDACTED
```

But I have had **no success** authenticating using the Go or Postman implementations of Oauth 1.0. For Go, I wrote this [sample client](https://github.com/natemurthy/etrade-api/blob/main/golang/main.go) using the [dghubble/oauth1](https://github.com/dghubble/oauth1) library, and for Postman I am using the built-in auth tool.

My trouble is largely with generating the correct `oauth_signature` in each of these. I always get this error:

[image: invalid signature]

Or if I try to plug-and-play the access token I obtained from Etrade's sample Python client into Postman when, for instance, accessing the `/accounts/list` API endpoint, the response I receive is:

```
<Error>
  <message>oauth_problem=signature_invalid</message>
</Error>
```

It's strange that their Python example (which uses [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth)) has a different behavior than Go or Postman. Seems that Etrade does something non-standard that fits the `requests.Session` shape of the `rauth` implementation. Is there a way to know if I'm generating my signatures correctly for any implementation I use?

**Appendix:**

Sample Postman requests:

[image: postman: request_token]
[image: postman: auth url]
[image: postman: access_token]

Capture of session attributes when using Python `rauth` library (sensitive info redacted):
https://gist.github.com/natemurthy/a7f628e44da9651d0676291803915c9c

Comparison of HTTP headers when calling `/v1/accounts/list` between Python vs Go:

Python:

```
GET https://api.etrade.com/v1/accounts/list.json

{'Authorization': 'OAuth realm="",oauth_consumer_key=REDACTED",oauth_nonce="22d0b83e4cba610148c990fdab1c327948a10677",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1668988571",oauth_token="REDACTED",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="REDACTED"'}

Response: 200 OK
```

Go:

```
GET https://api.etrade.com/v1/accounts/list.json

map[Authorization:[OAuth oauth_consumer_key="REDACTED", oauth_nonce="eZ1twhwIs7f3wD90uOelpuNNAE2RZ8wkQm4gEKvlklM%3D", oauth_signature="REDACTED", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1669074040", oauth_token="REDACTED", oauth_version="1.0"]]

Response: 401 Unauthorized
{"Error":{"message":"oauth_problem=signature_invalid"}}
```

Comment: I authenticated from C# which didn't use rauth, so special behavior seems unlikely.

Comment: Can you use Postman to monitor your Python connection and see the difference? If it can't decrypt your SSL connection, try Fiddler to get the details and then put those into Postman.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the C# examples work fine (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62367417/e-trade-requesting-access-token-i-get-signature-invalid), but I don't have a deterministic way of creating a side-by-side comparison of the Python request and the Postman request (unless I can fix the nonce and timestamps in both requests to be the same)

Comment: A) Why do you care about getting it to work from Postman?   
B) Can you post the python and Postman requests as part of your question?  We are not going to be much help if we can't see what we are working with.

Comment: A) I mainly care about getting it to work with Go. Getting it to work with Postman is just to reproduce the behavior in a different client.

B) I added some sample Postman screenshots in the "Appendix" above. Haven't had time to do a wireshark/tcpdump of the Python request, but I added a gist the shows the session attributes filled in from the rauth access_token step

Comment: My next step would be to monitor and compare the requests that are actually being sent using Fiddler and see what is different. I just had a case yesterday that I couldn't get sorted until I noticed in Fiddler that one was sending a GET and the other HEAD. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Looks like Fiddler is about $120/year. Worth it? https://www.telerik.com/purchase/fiddler

Comment: Fiddler Classic (Windows only) is free, or the 10 day trial. Either should be enough to solve your immediate problem. Beyond that, it would depend on how much you'd use it.

Comment: I added a comparison of HTTP headers when calling `/v1/accounts/list` between the Python vs Go requests in the Appendix above. The only real difference I see is that the the latter request does not have `realm=""` set., which appears to be the _more_ correct thing to do according to RFC 5849 3.4.1.3 https://github.com/dghubble/oauth1/blob/main/auther.go#L226